How can I stop a foreground service from the client?
I am unable to find how to stop my foreground service (and remove the notification) from my MainActivity.  I am trying to implement a toggle image button.  I can start the service with the button but I can't stop it.
public void onClickImageButton(View view) {
    // try stopping, otherwise start
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpeechRecognitionService.class);
    if(context.stopService(intent)) {
        ImageButton button = this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 60, 47, 47));
        isBound = false;
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(context, SpeechRecognitionService.class);
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
        bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}

context.stopService(intent) returns true every button press after the first one and I have confirmed the service still functions after trying to stop it.
In my service class's onStartCommand() I have it return START_STICKY.  I tried START_NOT_STICKY with no effect.

I have to unbind the MainActivity from the service before stopping the service, otherwise the service will not stop across an orientation change.  I used a global state variable isBound to track bound state.
public void onClickImageButton(View view) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpeechRecognitionService.class);
    if(isBound) {
        unbindService(connection);
        context.stopService(intent);
        ImageButton button = this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 60, 47, 47));
        isBound = false;
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(context, SpeechRecognitionService.class);
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
        bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}

